# fail2ban.action ERROR iptables -w -N f2b-<jail-name>

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, fail2ban

I've been using fail2ban for a while without any issues.

The other day, I decided to stop fail2ban to remove one rule from my default iptables. When I started fail2ban, it started ok (according to the command: service fail2ban start).

However, when I checked iptables, I didn't see fail2ban chains added. I checked fail2ban log and I found several error like these:

> fail2ban.action         [32091]: ERROR   iptables -w -N f2b-
>   iptables -w -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 0:65535 -j f2b- -- stderr: "iptables v1.4.7: option `-w' requires an argument\nTry`iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.\niptables v1.4.7: option `-w' requires an argument\nTry`iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.\niptables v1.4.7: option `-w' requires an argument\nTry`iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.\n"

From this log, it seems fail2ban is trying to run iptables with the `-w` option, which doesn't exist. I checked all the fail2ban configuration files, specially under action.d directory, and there isn't a single line with the `-w` option. How weird is that?

I have no clue what is happening here, and I'm unable to use fail2ban because of this.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

The `-w` option is not in your version 1.4.7 of iptables,it's use is explained in the /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-common.conf file

```
# Option:  lockingopt
# Notes.:  Option was introduced to iptables to prevent multiple instances from
#          running concurrently and causing irratic behavior.  -w was introduced
#          in iptables 1.4.20, so might be absent on older systems
#          See https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1122
# Values:  STRING
lockingopt = -w
```

I would be tempted to remove the -w from the above declaration or even comment it out and see what happened.

---

Check your yum.log to see if fail2ban was updated recently. if so, see when it happened and check to see if you have a yumcron job running about that time.

Comment: Yes!!!! You got it. I commented that line, and also changed this #iptables = iptables <lockingopt> to  iptables = iptables.

Comment: I still don't know why I started having this issue since my iptables and fail2ban packages were not changed.

Comment: I had the same issue and removing -w from lockingopt and restarting fail2ban fixed it. @GreenTeaTech: please accept this answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: @GreenTeaTech given that the problem didn't appear until you restarted fail2ban, it may have been a *long* time since the broken package was installed.  Any time back to when the machine was last rebooted.

Answer (score 1):

best approch is to add :

[Init]
lockingopt =

in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

the -w option description :

```
# Option:  lockingopt
# Notes.:  Option was introduced to iptables to prevent multiple      instances from
#          running concurrently and causing irratic behavior.  -w was introduced
#          in iptables 1.4.20, so might be absent on older systems
#          See https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1122
# Values:  STRING
```

while in centos 6.7 the iptable version is 1.4.7 so it won't work.

additional information are here :

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1272681
https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1122